# Close Votes shortcut tags should be tailored per user

Tags: feature-request, tags, vote-to-close, tag-watching, filtering

Looking at the [review queue page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), the Close Votes queue has various tag shortcuts to review items by a specific tag:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

3 of the items in that list aren't in tags I'm interested in, the other 2 that appear are just coincidentally in my favorites.

The 5 tags shown are the most popular tags on the site, and are likely to have the most close votes against them, regardless of whether they are actually relevant to the user that is reviewing.

I already have the following [filters in the Close Votes queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7529057?filter-tags=sql-server%20knockoutjs%20c%23), and I have my favorite tags:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Tailored Tags**

I suggest it would be better to show either existing filters from the close votes queue or favorite tags in this shortcut list if they have been configured, or a combination. Surely those tags will be more applicable to anyone reviewing and will be more likely to be used. I'm never going to click on [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), not even for fun!

**Edge cases:**

If no filters or favorites are configured, the existing view should be the default view.

If there are no "Close Votes" under the tags that a user has configured (I know that's unlikely), then the tags could be filled with some of the default tags to bring it up to 5 items.

Comment: "Are they just the tags with the highest close vote count as they don't appear to change?" Those are the same tags I see in the queue, and they're also the five most popular tags on Stack Overflow (just in a different order). It makes sense that they'd be the ones with the highest close vote count.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I thought as much, thanks for confirming.