# How to change review by tag in the review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues

I am going to review close votes. For that I click on review and I see following screen. There indicates review `by tag` and review `by type`.

[image]

Now, if I want to review by `HTML` or `CSS` but it didn't show to me. So, how can I select it? Is there any way to select another tag?

Comment: Related feature-request : [Close Votes shortcut tags should be tailored per user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289034/close-votes-shortcut-tags-should-be-tailored-per-user)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can filter by tags once you're in the queue, by using the "filter" link:

> [image]

The dialog box also lets you select close reasons to filter on if you wish.