# Sort review queues according to user's own tags

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

SO's review queues show mostly tags I am not interested in. Currently, I can only filter for three tags I want to review. In some sense, this seems a bit too harsh.

Suggestion: Sort the review queues according to a user's tags' answer score. So always start first with the items a user is most competent at.

Expected result: I expect that with this improvement, experienced users would review more in their area of interest which most probably goes beyond three tags.

Comment: *" In some sense, this seems a bit too harsh"*...in what sense, exactly? I don't necessarily think this is a "bad" feature request but I'm also not sure you've made a great case for it. You can currently filter by 3 tags and it saves your filter each time. If this were a feature, there would still need to be a way to filter manually if, say, there were no more review items in your tags.

Comment: @codeMagic: If I decide for 3 tags, I take those I am most interested in. But then I also decide to not see anything else. With the proposed approach, I would see also those items I am "a bit" interested in ; interest would rather fade out slowly - so I would effectively review more than now - without going against my interests.

Comment: Related? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289034/close-votes-shortcut-tags-should-be-tailored-per-user

Answer (score 3):

I've started to be active in the review queues of Emacs.SX, but I can't seem to get nearly as motivated for the SO review queues: not only they're dishearteningly long, but on top of that each review takes me a *lot of* time to try and understand what this is about and whether the question/answer makes sense, and in many cases I end up skipping because I don't feel like I know what to choose (which is the worst outcome, since it means my time was completely wasted).

So I'm much slower and less effective reviewing in SO than in Emacs.SX.

Sorting the queues according to my tags would let me focus on those posts where I can give a quick high quality review.  As it stands, I feel like reviewing for SO is a waste of my time (so I don't do it very much), but my experience with Emacs.SX makes me think that I might change my opinion if the reviews were sorted according to my tags.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend that the tags associated with a Question be displayed in the Reviewer window **above the Question**.

That way, the Reviewer can quickly identify those Questions related to his personal strengths, skills or interests ... and minimize time/effort spent before choosing "Skip" option.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional viewpoint on this topic, I would like to suggest that once you are granted the "**Reviewer**" status, you would have a new Section displayed under your "**Profile**" where you can choose/specify ...

**Level 1 filter:**

- Review Questions for all SO Communities where member
- Review Questions for selected SO Communities where member (*Members would understandably have preferences about which Communities they would prefer being active in this manner*)

**Level 2 filter:**

- Review Questions for any Member
- Review Questions for specified Members (*used to monitor problematic Members*)
- Review Questions for Members with reputation OVER 100K (*this would allow focus on questions likely of more advanced/complex/esoteric nature where more experienced Member likely will "advance" the state of general knowledge through more pointed questions/answers in likely niche or high-impact topics*)
- Review Questions for Members with reputation BELOW 5K (*this would allow Members with a strong "educator" approach to have high-impact on early learning faced by novices*)

**Level 3 filter:**

- Review Questions for ALL topics
- Review Questions for Member-specfied tags

Comment: What do you mean by „SO Communities“? The closest I can think of are collectives, but they cover only very few tags.

Comment: "_Review Questions for specified Members_" reviews aren't for users, reviews are for questions / answers.

Comment: StackOverflow, Vim & Vi, Unix & Linux are what I call Communities.

Comment: Review queues are already per Stack *Exchange* community.

Comment: After spending 2 separate evenings doing "Triage" and only encountering 4 total cases out of over 5500 reviews where I did not skip, I find it fruitless to have StackOverflow grant such a "privilege" at such a low Points rating, without being able to specify the tags to match the Member's knowledge/skills set.  How does one go about opting out of this access level.